# CV Does Not Work From Cron

Tags: cron, cron-job, cv

I am having an issue in Amazon Linux 2 where I can run cv commands from the command line but I cannot run cv commands from cron.

For example:

```
/usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/cv  api job.execute --user=cronusersupport --cwd=/var/app/current
```

This command will run perfectly from the command line using the default ec2-user account.
Running this command from cron while logged in as the same user will produce:

```
In civicrm.settings.php line 569:

  [Error]
  Failed opening required 'CRM/Core/ClassLoader.php' (include_path='.::/packa
  ges:.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear')
```

I have been logging the output to a file. So my actual crontab looks like this:

```
*/15 * * * * /usr/bin/php /usr/local/bin/cv  api job.execute --user=cronusersupport --cwd=/var/app/current -vvv >> /opt/paao_civi_cron.txt 2>&1
```

I have even tried adding `cd /var/app/current &&` before this command to make sure the command is running from the correct place.

I have checked the verbose output and the last step that works correctly is `[Bootstrap:debug] Load settings file "/var/app/current/web/sites/default/civicrm.settings.php"`.

I have worked with AWS support on this and we tried things like making sure my $PATH was correct,  running the command as an sh script,  trying to run as the webapp user who owns the files,  and I have even added the $civicrm_root to line 569 of civicrm.settings.php to see if that would work.

I have the following config:

EC2 instance with remote RDS server. The server is running well for HTTP requests and cv commands when not run from cron.

Drupal -  9.5

CiviCRM -5.64.4

CV - 0.3.48

PHP - 8.0.30

If anyone has any ideas I would be very thankful as I am at a loss here.

I have the same setup working on Ubuntu and it is working perfectly.

Thanks!

Comment: How have you defined civicrm_root in civicrm.settings.php? It seems like it's blank.

Comment: @Demerit, $civicrm_root is set to /var/app/current/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core - thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I double checked and to clarify that there is a / at the end (/var/app/current/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/).  Thanks!

Comment: The reason I'm asking is because if you look at [the lines](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/fbf738ed82313a0d6a3e5b873503244e82baf373/templates/CRM/common/civicrm.settings.php.template#L612) where it sets the include_path, your include_path looks exactly like what it would look like if $civicrm_root was blank. Is there maybe a second place in the file where it's blanking out $civicrm_root?

Comment: @Demerit, I will do another analysis but that appears unlikely to me because the command runs from the command line just not from cron. If the variable was bank then I would think it would break in all cases.

Comment: If you had a line like `$civicrm_root=$_ENV['something'];` then it's possible that might work from your login shell but come out blank during cron.

Comment: @Demerit, you hit it right on the nose. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was $civicrm_root being set in civicrm.settings.php based on an environment variable, which wasn't set during cron.